# Route prefixes in NestJS

Tags: routes, nestjs

I have a bunch of modules that logically belong together, and should be namespaces under `/api`. I've been trying every which way to make it work with the `RouterModule` as well as with `nest-router`, and for some reason I cannot seem to make it work. As soon as I put my modules in either `nest-router`'s `RouterModule.forRoutes(routes)`, or in the built-in `RouterModule`'s `RouterModule.register([])` call, the modules don't even get initialized anymore:

Before:

```bash
[Nest] 40601  - 17/11/2022, 15:29:26     LOG [InstanceLoader] ViewModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 40601  - 17/11/2022, 15:29:26     LOG [InstanceLoader] CacheableModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 40601  - 17/11/2022, 15:29:26     LOG [InstanceLoader] JobApplicationModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 40601  - 17/11/2022, 15:29:26     LOG [InstanceLoader] CandidateProfileModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 40601  - 17/11/2022, 15:29:26     LOG [InstanceLoader] BrandModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 40601  - 17/11/2022, 15:29:26     LOG [InstanceLoader] OtpModule dependencies initialized +1ms
{"level":40,"time":1668695365622,"pid":40601,"hostname":"SLBR62611.local","msg":"Preflight conditions have not passed, disabling APM."}
```

after:

```bash
[Nest] 40618  - 17/11/2022, 15:29:52     LOG [InstanceLoader] ViewModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 40618  - 17/11/2022, 15:29:52     LOG [InstanceLoader] CacheableModule dependencies initialized +0ms
{"level":40,"time":1668695391435,"pid":40618,"hostname":"SLBR62611.local","msg":"Preflight conditions have not passed, disabling APM."}
```

Even if I strip down my `routes` file to just this, the modules & their controllers and routes don't get loaded:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/otp',
    module: OtpModule,
  },
  {
    path: '/job-applications/:applicationId',
    module: BrandModule,
  },
];
```

Comment: Of course, a lot depends on your code (which you should have posted here), but the NestJS router is really strange in [some cases](https://dev.to/kostyatretyak/nestjs-vs-ditsmod-features-of-the-router-and-dynamic-modules-3gin).